# How do I calculate this time? Across midnight

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with start and end dates and values.

In C I have start date.
In E I have end date.

In I I have start time. (06:05:00)
In J I have end time. (08:33:00)

If C <>E I need to add 24 hours to the time elapsed.

How can I do that?

I tried `if(C2<>E2;1+J2-I2;"omitted")`
But I get the result 21:32:00.
It should be about 26 hours
(24+8-6 = 26 if we only look at the hours).

What have I done wrong?

Edit;
Back at work and can now upload some images.
**Method 1**

[image]

**Method 2**

[image]

Both return the wrong time.

EDIT2;
**Method 3**
I remember how I always have to format the dates from "our" format to Excels format for it to be recognized as a date.
In column P I use RIGHT(), MID(), and LEFT() to make a correct formatted date.
In R and S I use the same as P&Q column.

[image] 
Still not correct.
:-/

EDIT again:

[image]

Comment: It works successfully for me, giving me a result of `26:28` (when formatted as `[hh]:mm`).

Comment: I get the result of `21:32` when the subtraction is reversed, so maybe that's all the problem is?

Comment: Id be concerned if C <> E and it's more than 2 days difference.  You're just adding one.  By adding the time to the date and then subtracting the differences of end from start, you get the exact difference.  you can then format the output to display it however you desire (within limits of the format functions)

Comment: I'm not at work anymore so I have to look at this tomorrow. But no it's not a problem with C<>E. It is never more than one day. It's start and end times of picking customer orders and if it's not the same day it's across midnight. It's never two days. The only time it goes across days is between Friday and Saturday or Saturday and Sunday. Never both.

Comment: @tigeravatar You are correct about 21:32. That was when I was desperate and tried all possible ways and I tried to do the math the other way around. But as you can see from the images above I (now) use the correct formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula: `=(E1+J1)-(C1+I1)`  we just add the date and time together and subtract the end from start and then format the cell having the formula to show days, hours, minutes.

This way, if you have more than 1 day difference, you're not just adding 24 hours.

Change the format of the target cell contianing the above formula to 
`d "days" hh "hours" mm "minutes"` 
or use the format tigerAvatar suggested of `[hh]:mm` if you want the hours to be cumulative across days.

Then you get a nice output of: `2 days 02 hours 28 minutes` or `50:28`

Feel free to drop the 1 h or 1 m if you don't want the leading zeros.

A picture is worth a 1000 words so:
[image]

Version 2 after your screenshots: I don't think C, E are in date format based on your updates so...
 I used formula`=(DATE(LEFT(E2,4),MID(E2,5,2),RIGHT(E2,2))+J2)-(DATE(LEFT(C2,4),MID(C2,5,2),RIGHT(C2,2))+I2)` in K and custom format mask: [h]:mm
If this doesn't work it may be a regional setting and the interpretation of `[h]:mm`  I am assuming I/J are time formats.

[image]

Comment: I tried this method also now but still get the wrong time returned. See my updated question.

Comment: I did assume that columns C/E were date and I/J were time is this correct?  (no based on screenshots) Tried using this formula in col K: `=(DATE(LEFT(E2,4),MID(E2,5,2),RIGHT(E2,2))+J2)-(DATE(LEFT(C2,4),MID(C2,5,2),RIGHT(C2,2))+I2)` and set the format to custom `[h]:mm`  seems to work.  I still prefer this approach instead of adding 1 day just incase.

Comment: In your 3rd method I don't see where you cast the result to a date.  It's not jsut about the format, it also matters what data type is.  By ensuring those columns are DATEs and then adding them I think we can get the correct results.

Comment: In column Q of "method 3" you see I add date with time. If I change the format of the cell to `<date> <time>` it returns `2017-08-05 08:33` but still, even with both start and end like that it still only returns 02:28

Comment: In your 3rd method I don't see where you cast the result to a date.  I see it being split out as a string but not converted to a date.  use date(YYYY,MM,DD) instead of the "-" and then add in the time.  My version 2 above.

Comment: I have never had to do a Date() before.. It always work when I use the "-" to split the string. If I use TEXT() on the split string it can return "Monday" for example. So it should be able to read it as a date. But I will try and use Date()

Comment: It was the DATE() that was missing. I have always thought Excel could understand the string when it was split with "-" since it has worked in all other calculations and formulas. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Implicit conversions can sometimes not work as expected.  Being explicit can alleviate headaches!